# Issue with service fabric resource manager file deployment (apim.json and apim.parameters)

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-api-management, service-fabric-stateless, ibm-api-management

My requirement is as follows:

I have an web API whose port I have removed from the ServiceManifest.xml file. This is done so that I can implement multiple node multiple calls feature from API management. (i.e. I want to remove dependency on port number)

While deploying API management resource files, I am facing issues while deploying apim.json and apim.parameters.json file.

Following is the exception I am getting always.
"Service activation failed. Please look at the details in Activity Log on the left side. In case you are deploying into VNET please make sure prerequisites are followed as described on https://aka.ms/apiminvnet"

There is nothing in the log files when I am uploading.

I am using following link for the deployment and testing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-deploy-api-management

I am getting exception in running powershell script

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $groupname -TemplateFile "$templatepath\apim.json" -TemplateParameterFile "$templatepath\apim.parameters.json" -Verbose

Comment: I recommend you retag to API Management

Comment: Can you share service name you tried to create?